# Source bash script in modulefile with environment-modules version 3.2.10

Tags: linux, bash, centos-7

I'm trying to source a bash script as part of a module load in CentOS 7, using the default environment-modules package (version 3.2.10), example as follows:

```
#%Module1.0#####################################################################
##
## example modulefile
##
## modulefiles/example.  Generated from null.in by configure.
##
proc ModulesHelp { } {
        global version

        puts stderr "\tThis module sets up environment for the"
        puts stderr "\texample module "
        puts stderr "\n\tVersion $version\n"
}

module-whatis   "example"


setenv EX_HOME /path/to/install
prepend-path PATH $env(EX_HOME)/bin/

source $env(EX_HOME)/configs/*.bashrc
```

This fails with the following error:

```
$ module load example/v1 
example/v1(21):ERROR:102: Tcl command execution failed: source $env(EX_HOME)/configs/*.bashrc
```

I'm aware that this is possible with modules version 4 with the line

```
source-sh bash $env(EX_HOME)/configs/*.bashrc
```

But we have many other modules in use, all of which are written for version 3 and I can't afford changing to version 4 the whole system and risk breaking functionality. Is there a workaround, or a native way to do this in version 3.2.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On CentOS 7, Modules is shipped with an utility named `createmodule.sh` that takes a sh shell script as argument and outputs the modulefile commands that correspond to the environment changes performed by the script if sourced.

One way to achieve what you want is to call this script within a modulefile, with a bit a Tcl code around it to save the changes made in a separate environment variable, in order to be able to undo them when unloading the module.

```
#%Module

switch -- [module-info mode] {
    load - display {
        set sourcesh [exec /usr/share/Modules/bin/createmodule.sh test.sh]
        # remove modulefile header
        set sourcesh [string range $sourcesh 13 end] 
        eval $sourcesh
        # record content in environment to remember it when unloading
        setenv TEST_SOURCED_SCRIPT [string map {\n ;} $sourcesh]
    }
    unload {
        if {[info exists env(TEST_SOURCED_SCRIPT)]} {
            eval $env(TEST_SOURCED_SCRIPT)
            # unset variable as we are unloading
            setenv TEST_SOURCED_SCRIPT $env(TEST_SOURCED_SCRIPT)
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code snippet, change the `test.sh` reference by the script you want to *source*.

This is a bit hacky but it should work with simple scripts. Indeed best way to achieve what you want is migrating to Modules 4.6+ and use the new [`source-sh`](https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modulefile.html#mfcmd-source-sh) modulefile command.

Note that if Modules 4+ is built with the `--enable-compat-version` option, it also install a Modules 3.2 version and a `switchml` alias to easily switch between old and new version of Modules. It could help you to migrate progressively.

Answer (score 1):

There is **env2** script command from whcih we can change from script to Modulefile format.Using Above,we can create modulefile(i.e software-2023.1) with syntax #%module and required line. Then execute below command.
Eg: env2 -from bash -to modulecmd ******Script_path***/setup*** >> **output_path/module/modulefile/software-2023.1**

Note:It appends the scripts environment varible in module file.